# What are the bad effects of writing duplicate CSS?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I want to know, how CSS get rendered in the browser. what is wrong in writing duplicate CSS property on hover as below.

```
span.addMedication .two-way-toggle-big
{
    display: inline-block;
    border: solid 1px orange;
    padding: 15px;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 100;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 70px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}
span.addMedication .two-way-toggle-big:hover
{
    display: inline-block;
    border: solid 1px orange;
    padding: 15px;
    background-color: rgb(247, 157, 32);
    color: white;
    font-size: 15px;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 70px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: No problem. You don't have a duplicated selector, because `:hover` is a pseudoselector.

Comment: There is nothing 'wrong'. I don't know why you'd duplicate those properties as they'll be inherited when setting the hover style, and having them commented out as a reminder means you've got two sets of properties to keep updated. Drop the commented lines and you've arrived at what i would consider 'best practice'

Comment: one of my friend written the code as above but i am not satisfy. why he written the duplicate code but i am not able to justify what is wrong with the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically it's nothing wrong, but you shouldn't do it anyways. CSS is actually thought to cascade, so you would want to work accordingly.

It bloats up your file and your file size, but the biggest problem for me is **readability**:

In your code I can not see at once what changes on `:hover`, I have to look at it longer, as with following you know at once:

```
span {
    display: inline-block;
    border: solid 1px orange;
    padding: 15px;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 100;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 70px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}
span:hover {
    background-color: rgb(247, 157, 32);
    color: white;
}
```

If you are interested there are lots of different [CSS-Style-Guides](https://css-tricks.com/css-style-guides/), that are meant to make your writing more maintainable. Just have a look ;)